# What are fundamental differences between ParquetReader and ParquetFileReader?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I'm writing a thin library for accessing HDFS.

I found two classes related to parquet files.
One is `ParquetReader` and the other is `ParquetFileReader`.

What are differences between `ParquetReader` and `ParquetFileReader`? Are those classes basically work as same?

Comment: `ParquetFileReader` has a lot more static utility methods while the other appears to be more POJO-like. Neither is very suitable for a "thin-client" since you still require parquet-hadoop and hadoop-client dependencies